# AbstractMethodError upon creation of new StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I've been having problems trying to instantiante a new StreamingContext of Spark Streaming.

I'm trying to create a new StreamingContext, but an error of AbstractMethodError is being thrown.
I've been debugging the stack trace and found out that when the third Spark ListenerBus is being created inside the StreamingListenerBus, the application stops and throws this error.

Below is the code I'm trying to execute

```scala
package platform.etl

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object ClickGeneratorStreaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ClickGeneratorStreaming").setMaster("local[*]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10)

  }
}
```

And here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.$init$(ListenerBus.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListenerBus.<init>(StreamingListenerBus.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.<init>(JobScheduler.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:84)
    at platform.etl.ClickGeneratorStreaming$.main(ClickGeneratorStreaming.scala:10)
    at platform.etl.ClickGeneratorStreaming.main(ClickGeneratorStreaming.scala)
```

My build.sbt

```
name := "spark"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292"
val sparkKafkaVersion = "2.3.0"
val argonautVersion = "6.2"

resolvers += "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io"
resolvers += "horton" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "horton2" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet")
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.7.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.softwaremill.sttp" %% "core" % "1.2.0-RC2"
libraryDependencies += "com.softwaremill.retry" %% "retry" % "0.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % argonautVersion
libraryDependencies += "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut-monocle" % argonautVersion
libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.mrpowers" % "spark-fast-tests" % "v2.3.0_0.11.0" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % "5.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.redislabs" % "spark-redis" % "2.3.1-M2"
libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % sparkVersion


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "application.conf"            => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "reference.conf"              => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

My plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Comment: Could you also include plugins.sbt please? Is it only assembly plugin you use?

Comment: Classic dependency hell. Do you really need that many dependencies? Can you not start with latest spark streaming?

Comment: I've included my plugins.sbt, this is a pretty big project, unfortunately, and one part of it must have a real-time processing pipeline.

Comment: While trying to find out more information about the problems, I've removed my ivy cache and redownloaded the dependencies, and this message came up
[warn]  * org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292 is selected over 2.1.0
[warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.1.0        (depends on 2.1.0)

Comment: There is a lot of evictions in your project. Try running https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph to find out offensive libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
Looks like I forgot to add the `spark-streaming` dependency on my build.sbt, and for some reason, It found a way to use a dependency of dependency on my import, making it use a different version of `spark-streaming` which is not compatible with my spark version.

To solve that I just added a single newline at my build.sbt

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
```

And it works flawlessly now.